# Creating MS Word 2010 Relative Links?

Tags: microsoft-word, hyperlink

Okay here is what I've tried so far for creating relative links in my MS Word Documents.

1. In my document from the ribbon I select the `File` tab.
2. I then select `Info` from the side bar.
3. Click the properties drop down from the right hand column. (a bit difficult to find initially, since it looks like text not a drop down, but it's there).
4. Click Advanced Properties
5. The <document-name>.docx Properties Dialog Appears
6. I enter `.\` to specify that I want a relative path for the links in my document.
7. I click OK.
8. I go back into my document select some text and attempt to make a link out of it clicking the `Insert` tab of the ribbon, and then clicking `Hyperlink`.
9. I then select a document from the current folder, and strip the full path from it, leaving just the name of the .docx file to which I wish to link.
10. Then I click `OK`.
11. The link appears, I try to click it using Ctrl+Click.  I am informed that the address of the site is not valid.  Check the address and try again.

What could I possibly be doing wrong here?  I just want a relative link.  It's so easy in to do this in HTML.

Comment: So there's no way to do this then?  I guess a Word document is not an HTML document.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's definitly possible, infact I managed to do it quickly by inserting a regular hyperlink and without having to do any extra steps.

I would suggest to remove the results of any special steps that changed advanced properties and try the following steps:

1. Click Quick Parts -> Hyperlink
2. Click Existing File or Page -> Current Folder
3. Pick a document then click bookmark and Ok
4. Click Ok to the main dialog.

If you press CTRL+F9 only the file name without path should appear. Try clicking using the link now. If the full path still appears then try removing it and only leaving the file name.

Here's what the field code looks like:

```
{ HYPERLINK "MyDocument.docx" \l "Mybookmark" }
```